# MagicZoom fast changing between 2 pictures

Tags: jquery, magiczoom

I faced with a trouble using magicZoom. 
When I'm fast change between 2 pictures which are have activated magicZoom, magicZoom library shows me in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
    at d.eval (eval at <anonymous> (magiczoom.min.js:11), <anonymous>:1:84962)
    at Function.eval (eval at <anonymous> (magiczoom.min.js:11), <anonymous>:1:4601)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (magiczoom.min.js:11), <anonymous>:1:4880)
```

- Here's additional information:

  1. Magic Zoom version number : Magic Zoom Plus v4.5.39.
  2. Magic Zoom settings used on the page.: I'm using such API methods as MagicZoom.update, MagicZoom.refresh(node>).
  3. What other JavaScript is running on the page (this can affect Magic Zoom). :  mustache.min.js, device.min.js, amplience-sdk-client.min.js, jcarousel.min.js.

It works fine, but how can I prevent these errors in the log?
Do you have any thoughts about that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question, please supply the following information:

1. Magic Zoom version number.
2. Magic Zoom settings used on the page.
3. What other JavaScript is running on the page (this can affect Magic Zoom).

**Update on 22 March:**

Based upon the extra information:

1. Magic Zoom Plus v4.5.x is outdated and no longer supported. The latest version is v5.2.2 ([changelog](https://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/#changelog)). Please download the latest version of your license - it is often a free upgrade.
2. Magic Zoom Plus v4.5.x does not include MagicZoom.update, MagicZoom.refresh or the other MagicZoom.* API methods. All the API methods in v4.5.x start with MagicZoomPlus.

If you post the URL of your page, we can provide additional advice. If you can't post the live URL publicly, you should send it to Magic Toolbox via the [secure contact form](https://www.magictoolbox.com/contact/).